# Proof using theory of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

There are unique functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f′(x) = g(x) \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R};$$ 
$$g′(x) = −f(x) \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R};$$
$$f(0) = 0;$$ 
$$g(0) = 1.$$

I will have to show $(f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2 = 1$.

My solution:

Let $h(x) = (f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ 
Then I can show $h′(x) = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
This implies $h(x)$ is a constant. Suppose $h(x) = a$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. 
However I am stuck here and struggling to find a way to show $a = 1$.

Is there a way to show $a = 1$?

Thanks.

Comment: As it is contant, it should be equal to its value on a particular point. Use the initial data of $f$ and $g$ to compute this contant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=h(0)=f(0)^2+g(0)^2=0+1^2=1.$